# seekbar does not reach upto the end

Tags: android

I am developing one app where i am using seekbar . My seekbar is  having maximum value 6 i.e android:max="6"  as i want to have intervals of 5. My problem is seekbar does not reach upto the end i tried many things but still helpless so can anybody suggest me what to do.
My code is

```
 public class MainActivity  extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener 
  {

    SeekBar seekBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
  int max = 6;
seekBar.setMax(max);
seekBar.setProgress(0);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {


}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // Notify that the user has started a touch gesture.


}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // Notify that the user has finished a touch gesture.

}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more clear? What does it mean: " seekbar does not reach upto the end"?

Comment: hey how did u manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          >

<SeekBar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:max="6"
      android:id="@+id/sb"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private SeekBar sb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
      sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sb);
      sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
     }


@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
}
```

[image]

All work like a charm. Hope it's help.

Comment: Its working properly if my max value is 100 . But i want intervals thats y i am changing it to 6.

Comment: you test on emulator or real device?

Comment: Try to create new project and use ONLY my code! Adds nothing - and test it.

Comment: Really - it's a magic. I tested it on 2 PC and 1 real device. Sorry - that is all how I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

try adding some padding at the end of seekbar:

myseekbar.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem (API 26, emulator) for 5 an 3 steps seekbars when I used [1:5] range -- the "thumb" was able to reach only "4". And also it seemed like touch is a bit missing the thumb to left side (but any other UI-components worked perfect).

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="5"
    android:min="1" />
```

Since I used mouse pointer and not finger -- all the advices about padding and margin didn't solve the problem.

Occasionally I discovered that if I use [0:4] range -- it gives whole movement up to the end so now my layout is:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    
    android:max="4"
    android:min="0"
    android:progress="2"
    
    android:maxHeight="13dp"
    android:minHeight="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bg_seek_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/ic_baseline_tag_faces_glad_24"
    android:thumbTint="@color/light_grey_A"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:tooltipText="@string/lbl_level">
```

It really strange that for small ranges you couldn't start from "1".